# Can you Point Targeted Prompts at Buttons Within a Component?

Tags: apex, lightning, metadata

We're currently trying to set up our In-App Guidance for when users first log into our app. Ideally, we wanted to use Targeted Prompts to point to the exact buttons that users would need to interact with. Unfortunately, Targeted Prompts seem very unspecific, only allowing the target to be the general container of an LWC (see screenshot and box highlighting where we want the prompt to point).

[image]

The metadata for Prompt does contain the argument `referenceElementContext` which I was hoping could be used to navigate deeper into the targeted element but it doesn't seem to work and ends up with either of the following scenarios:

1. An error pops up on the page saying "We can't find the element associated with this prompt. Contact your Salesforce admin for help."
2. Salesforce takes the first recognisable target and uses that, ignoring all attributes specified afterwards

The Metadata pulls down as follows:

```
<referenceElementContext>
{
    "component":"NAMESPACE:topOpportunitiesWrapper",
    "attributes":{
        "id":"topOpportunitiesWrapper"
    },
    "version":1
}
</referenceElementContext>
```

Is there a way/pattern to specify buttons or other focal points within the targeted container? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Cheers everyone